# Python get one element from string list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have both string list.

```
str1 = ["phone number", "phone #", "phone num"]
str2 = ["phone #", "invoice date", "invoice number"]
```

I want to find proper element from str2 array list under the condition of str1.

```
result = get_proper_element(str2, str1)
print(result)

phone #
```

Is there any python function or ML, Tensorflow API for this?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you exaplain what you mean by `proper element`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to get all strings common to both lists.

try this:

```py
str1 = ["phone number", "phone #", "phone num"]
str2 = ["phone #", "invoice date", "invoice number"]


def get_proper_element(str2, str1):
    return set(str2) & set(str1)


result = get_proper_element(str2, str1)
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Output:

> phone #

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are looking for the intersection of `str1` and `str2`, if that is the case you can convert them to `set` and do the intersection:

```py
str1 = ["phone number", "phone #", "phone num"]
str2 = ["phone #", "invoice date", "invoice number"]

result = set(str1).intersection(str2)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [any()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#any) function tests whether any item in the iterable evaluates to True to not. It accepts an iterable and returns True, if at least one item in the iterable is true, otherwise, it returns False.

```
str1 = ["phone number", "phone #", "phone num"]
str2 = ["phone #", "invoice date", "invoice number"]

for st1 in str2:
    if any(st in st1 for st in str1):
        print(st1)
```

O/P:

```
phone #
```